# Envers, father not revisioned on delete/create of a child

Tags: spring-boot, one-to-many, hibernate-envers, revision

I'm experiencing a problem with revisions on OneToMany relation tables

I have

```
@Audited
EntityA {
    @Id
    Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EntityB> entityBs;
}
```

and

```
@Audited
EntityB {

    @Id
    Integer id;

    @Column(name = "ENTITY_A_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long entityAId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_A_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private EntityA entityA;
}
```

I want that envers creates a new revision of EntityA everytime I delete or create EntityB.

Reading the docs I understand that org.hibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change is the right configuration property and is by default set to true.
So I can't understand why I don't see any new revision on EntityA when related EntityB is created or deleted.
I tried to create EntityB stand alone and I tried to create via

entityA.getEntityB().add(entityB)
repository.save(entityA)

but no revision of EntityA was saved

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

My configuration
spring boot: 2.4.4
hibernate/envers: 5.4.29
jdk 11

Comment: Please specify what you mean by father and child. The relation between those?

Comment: Yes, I have a OneToMany relation between EntityA and EntityB. When I create or delete EntityB, i want envers creates a new revision of related EntityA, checking entityB as modified